# include or includes

Tags: grammaticality

Here's the sentence: "CONAMES's Flight Performance Systems (FPS) product family includes solutions on aircraft that collect, process and convey valuable information used to increase the performance of the pilot and aircraft while increasing overall flight safety."

I'm not sure how I'd go with this.  It just doesn't read well either way.  (Company site 'About' copy.)

Comment: The FPS is a singular noun. Ergo, the verb is singular. But this should be on the other forum. Try: on-board solutions

Comment: It's the product family which is a singular noun.

Comment: "Includes" is correct (for the reason @MichaelHarvey gave); it's the rest of the sentence that "doesn't read well" (to put it mildly).